# trouble with creating a breadcrumb in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, breadcrumbs

I need advice on how to do breadcrumbs in asp classic

I have a company detail page - the thing is it could have been gotten to by a number of ways - through a area or through a list of categories and then companies
I want to show the breadcrumb that this user came to it
(and the same page can be gotten to in many ways)

I tried to build a session variable but if a user clicks the back key then it messed it up

any ideas?

Comment: Breadcrumbs are stateless. They should represent the current page's hierarchical position, not how a user got to the page. Find (or create) your Site Map and traverse it up to create the breadcrumbs for your company detail page.

Comment: @Phillip - you are correct in some aspects of what you say, but this is *Classic* ASP, not ASP.NET - Site Maps, unless you code them up yourself, are unavailable.

Comment: Phillip is correct in that when a user arrives at a particular page the breadcrumb should reflect the structure of the site, not how they navigate.

Comment: but the problem is teh person could have come to the page through many different ways  - so how do I know which one to show?

Answer (score 0):

When you design your site you need to work out, in your own mind (best to use a pencil and paper), just how the site links together and which pages can be considered to be related. I know this sounds pretty grey, but this is more a design principal than set in stone.

Word is a good tool to work this out. Flick into *Outline View* and use this to build up the structure.  The arrows on the ribbon at the top left allow you to indent and outdent your structure, and the markers at the beginning of the line allow you to drag and drop sections from one place to another.

Once you're happy about the structure you can update your pages to contain the stepped breadcrumb.  Unless you have heavily automated pages that change their structure vastly, or a site that is very fluid (changing it's structure frequently), I would simply hard code the breadcrumb in using an unordered list (`<ul>`).

It gets more complicated for Classic ASP if you want to be able to automate the breadcrumb. Firstly you'd need to decide what type of automation you want to use; for instance XML, like the .NET version, or a `global.asa` string/array version, or something that's read from your database...  The list goes on.

If you still find it difficult to get around the user's landing page train of thought, try using the search page on a site like the [NHS Data Dictionary](http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/web_site_content/navigation/main_menu.asp), or even try navigating using the links on the left.  The breadcrumb for this site is in the top banner - watch what happens when you switch between different links.

Hope this helps, but remember there's no right or wrong way to code up your links, it simply depends on the application or site you're creating.